# BCS external content type ReadList fails with InvalidMetadataObjectException

Tags: bcs, bdc, custom-bcs, custom-bdc

I have create a BDC model with a .Net assembly linking to a LOB system. Checking the model in Visual Studio is all good. I upload the solution to SharePoint 2013 Enterprise and create a new external list based on the external content type in my BDC model. So far, so good. But when I try to open the list to show all items (ReadList) it fails with user error

> Die Daten können nicht gerendert werden. Wenn das Problem weiterhin
>   besteht, wenden Sie sich an den Webserveradministrator. (Data could
>   not be rendered. Contact your system administrator)

In ULS there is a type load exception stating that my entity class OTUserEntity could not be loaded from Microsoft.BusinessData ??? (it's from, not by...).

But, when I debug the solution in Visual Studio I can see my code running and the class OTUserEntity being instatiated without problem. Still resulting in the same user error and ULS exception.

I already changed the naming as suggested in this post: InvalidMetadataObjectException while viewing external list but without luck.

I also did and IISRESET and even rebootet to avoid and old version dll conflict.

(Re-) Connecting the assembly to the LobSystem by doing Import-SPBusinessDataCatalogDotNetAssembly also did not help.
Ideas? Please!

Ben

**ULS**:

*InnerException 1: System.TypeLoadException: Der Typ "OmnitrackerProfileSyncBDC.OmnitrackerProfileSyncBDCModel.OTUserEntity" in der Assembly "Microsoft.BusinessData, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" konnte nicht geladen werden.     bei System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type)     bei System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.Infrastructure.DotNetTypeReflector.ResolveDotNetType(String abstractTypeName, ILobSystemStruct lobSystemStruct)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.Infrastructure.DotNetTypeReflector.GetDotNetType(ITypeDescriptor typeDescriptor)
Error while executing web part: Microsoft.BusinessData.MetadataModel.InvalidMetadataObjectException: Der Typ, der durch den 'TypeName' 'OmnitrackerProfileSyncBDC.OmnitrackerProfileSyncBDCModel.OTUserEntity' des 'TypeDescriptors' für den Parameter mit dem Namen 'oTUsersList' für die Methode mit dem Namen 'ReadList' für die Entität (externer Inhaltstyp) mit dem Namen 'OTUsers' im Namespace 'OmnitrackerProfileSyncBDC.OmnitrackerProfileSyncBDCModel' beschrieben wird, kann nicht geladen werden. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Der Typ "OmnitrackerProfileSyncBDC.OmnitrackerProfileSyncBDCModel.OTUserEntity" in der Assembly "Microsoft.BusinessData, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" konnte nicht geladen werden.     bei System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type)     bei System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.Infrastructure.DotNetTypeReflector.ResolveDotNetType(String abstractTypeName, ILobSystemStruct lobSystemStruct)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.Infrastructure.DotNetTypeReflector.GetDotNetType(ITypeDescriptor typeDescriptor)     --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.Infrastructure.DotNetTypeReflector.GetDotNetType(ITypeDescriptor typeDescriptor)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.Infrastructure.DotNetTypeReflector.GetValueFromInstanceUsingChildTypeDescriptor(Object instance, ITypeDescriptor typeDescriptor)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.Runtime.FieldValueHelpers.GetValue(Object adapter, ITypeDescriptor root, String dotNotation, IDictionary`2 cache)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.Runtime.FieldValueDictionary.get_Item(String fieldDotNotation)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListDataSource.GetFilteredEntityInstancesInternal(XmlDocument xdQueryView, Boolean fFormatDates, Boolean fUTCToLocal, String firstRowId, Int32 firstRowIndex, Boolean fBackwardsPaging, String& bdcidFirstRow, String& bdcidNextPageRow, List`1& lstColumnNames, Dictionary`2& dictColumnsUsed, List`1& mapRowOrdering, List`1& lstEntityData)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListDataSource.GetFilteredEntityInstances(XmlDocument xdQueryView, Boolean fFormatDates, Boolean fUTCToLocal, String firstRowId, Int32 firstRowIndex, Boolean fBackwardsPaging, String& bdcidFirstRow, String& bdcidNextPageRow, List`1& lstColumnNames, Dictionary`2& dictColumnsUsed, List`1& mapRowOrdering, List`1& lstEntityData)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureEntityDataViewAndOrdering(String& bdcidFirstRow, String& bdcidNextPageFirstRow)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureListItemsData()     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.get_Count()     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments selectArguments, String aggregateString, Boolean wantReturn, BaseXsltListWebPart webpart, SPListItem& listItem, SPListItemCollection& listItems, String[]& fieldList)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigatorInternal()     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigator()     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.RenderListData(XsltListViewWebPart xslWebPart, SPView view, TextWriter output)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.InplaceViewEditor.Execute(String strCmd)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.InplaceViewEditor.OnLoad(EventArgs e)*

Also posted on [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/18b088fa-a773-42ab-b702-0200a8a28488/bcs-external-content-type-readlist-fails-with-invalidmetadataobjectexception?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Two things were going wrong.

Firstly, Visual Studio scaffolded the BDC model such that reference to the type in the BDC model was like

```
<TypeDescriptor TypeName="MyBDCModel, MyEntityType" Name="MyEntityType">
```

Instead the type should be refernced by the fully qualified assembly name:

```
<TypeDescriptor TypeName="MyEntityNamespace.MyEntityType, MyEntitysAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=19cbd0ec1bd88206, processorArchitecture=MSIL" Name="MyEntityType">
```

Secondly, the missing type were located in another project/assembly in the same solution. For a BDC model using other projects one has to link those to the BDC model. You do this by opening the model's folder's property window -> Assemblies -> [...]. In the window that opens add the needed assemblies.